# Call to a view function returns an incorrect value

Tags: go-ethereum, storage, genesis

I'm currently developing a private network for a client using geth 1.11.3 and have encountered an unusual behavior. Here is a simple contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
 string public name;
 constructor(string memory _name) {
    name = _name;
 }
}
```

I aim to pre-deploy this contract via the genesis.json file, which is structured as follows:

```
{
  "config": {
    ...
  },
  "difficulty": "1",
  "gasLimit": "9000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    ...
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001001": {
      "balance": "0",
      "code": "compiled deployedBytecode",
      "storage": {
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000": "0x546f6b656e4e616d650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Upon initializing and running the node, I can successfully query the first storage slot using getStorageAt from ethers and get back the correct value. However, when I instantiate the contract and invoke the name() function, it yields an empty string.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The storage value for a string should contain the length of the string. The length value is located at the end of the slot. Your text is of 9 bytes (*2 hex chars per byte*), means `18` converted to `16 base` number is `12`. So the allocated value in genesis json should be:

```
0x546f6b656e4e616d650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012
```

Comment: Yes... The value was incorrect. Thanks!